# How do I run a TeamCity build as a specific user

Tags: teamcity

I have a build configuration which deploys my code to a machine.  Depending on which machine I am deploying to (e.g. dev/uat/prod), I need to run as a different user.

Rather than hardcoding the username and password in the build files (not really possible as they change regularly for security reasons) I would like to be able to type them in at the point I run the build.  I would envisage the "Run Custom Build" in TeamCity would have this option but I can't see anywhere to input that information.

Is there any way to do this (short of remoting into the build agent and changing the user which the build agent runs as)?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [RunAs plugin](https://github.com/pavelsher/runas/) combined with [TeamCity 7's new Typed Parameters](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Typed+Parameters) will let you make the password a "typed" parameter plugin.

Then, when it's entered at the Run screen, it will not be visible in the build history.

**EDIT:** Much later, as covered in the comments: You probably don't want to do this. Consider having separate pools which run as different users, and parameters to specify what builds are supported by what pools.

Comment: TeamCity 8 link to typed params: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Typed+Parameters

Comment: The runas plugin seems to run on EVERY build you have, which isn't going to work for me.  
Its also worth reading the documentation linked as the protection provided to the passwords entered isn't super strong.

Comment: This seems like a really insecure way to deal with credentials, as well as being a dormant project now.

Comment: Yes, I don't know what the "secure" way to do this is. There may not really be one. We have shifted to having each "pool" of agents run as a given user, and then certain builds are allowed to run on agents which need those users/permissions.

Comment: How about making the runas.password a required system property, and prompting it before running the build?

Answer (score 2):

Neil, you can pass build parameters via Run Custom Build dialog.

There are "System properties" and "Environment variables" sections, where you can add new build parameters or redefine existing ones.

Please read more: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Triggering+a+Custom+Build

Comment: Thanks - but how exactly would I use that to change the user account which the build runs as?

Comment: in your build file, (for instance, for Ant build runner),  you write ${deploy_user} and ${deploy_pwd} in the places, where username/password is present.

Comment: In build properties, you specify default values for variables 'deploy_user' and 'deploy_pwd'. 

When starting a build with RunCustomBuild dialog, you can specify any other parameters for 'deploy_user' and 'deploy_pwd', and they will be used in your build script, where you specified them.

You can use/set environment variables in the similar way, if your build doesn't support system properties.

Hope this helps

Comment: It would work but exposes my username and password to everyone else who can view the build history.Thanks anyway