# teamcity run build as specific user

Tags: build, teamcity

I have a need to execute build on a configuration under a specific user ID. How can I do this? I cannot switch the agent service to run as this user ID becuase I need to use this user or production ID only for this particular configuration. How can i do this in Teamcity?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223055/how-do-i-run-a-teamcity-build-as-a-specific-user

Comment: @MikeTwo - this solution doesnt scale too well for me. Our firm has a policy where the password is automatically changed every 2/3 months. I will have to remember to update the password every time. Also, putting the password in clear text doesn't sound right. Is there a better solution or has JetBrain added some feature to support this in newer versions?

Comment: I was not trying to say the answer was going to work. I was just pointing out there is a duplicate question.

Comment: I appreciate that Mike! Thanks. I was just trying to explain why the solution doesnt work for me.

Comment: @prakis - thanks for following up. I hope the runas plugin works for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [runAs](https://github.com/pavelsher/runas) TeamCity plugin.

Comment: That seems like what i exactly need. One question though, it mentions team city version 6.5.3. I am currently running 6.5.1, any chance it would work or will i need to upgrade?

Comment: Yes you need to update. Plugin uses an API which is first introduced in 6.5.3.

Comment: I upgraded and installed the plugin, thanks!. I had a quick question, The help says `teamcity.build.runAs.command="C:\\Program Files\\SysInternals\\psexec.exe" -u %runas.username% -p %runas.password% {start_build_script}`. Is this how i use this inside my custom build script? Or do is specify this in the build.properties file?

Comment: You can specify `%runas.username%` and `%runas.password%` in the build parameters of TeamCity build configuration

Answer (score 1):

Also new [RunAs TeamCity plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/teamcity-runas-plugin) for windows agents is available.