# How to run a Dotnet exe to run SQL queries using windows authentication?

Tags: .net, teamcity

I have build a dotnet application and able to run it through Teamcity pipeline.

When I use SQL authentication, queries are running as expected.

But I try using the same thing using windows authentication, its not working.

**Error: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.**

How to make this work?

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223055/how-do-i-run-a-teamcity-build-as-a-specific-user

Comment: I guess your teamcity server is not joined to the domain

Comment: The identity that is used as Trusted Connection is that of the process *running* the code, and that same identity mustbe known to SqlServer

Comment: Is the machine running this code joined to the same domain as the SQL Server machine, and does it have the necessary Windows credentials? If TeamCity itself uses Windows Authentication logins then you also need to setup constrained delegation

Comment: @HansKeﬆing, current parameters for windows authentication:

``
-s 10.0.x.x -d Sample -f D:\dotnet\tool -t true
``

Is it need to be changed something as follows:
``
-s 10.0.x.x -d Sample -f D:\dotnet\tool -u domain\user -pwd password -t true.
``
Is that correct?